# Nginx docker HTTPS connection

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, https

**nginx.conf:**

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;

pid /tmp/nginx.pid;

# turn off daemon mode to be watched by supervisord
daemon off;

pcre_jit on;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

# events block defines the parameters that affect connection processing.
events {
    # Define the maximum number of simultaneous connections that can be opened by a worker process
    worker_connections  1024;
}

# SSL configuration
server {
   listen 443 ssl http2;
   listen [::]:443 ssl http2;   
   server_name www.example.nl example.nl;
        ssl_certificate      /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.nl/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.nl/privkey.pem;
  
    # Improve HTTPS performance with session resumption
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;

    location / {
    try_files $uri @yourapplication;
    }
    
    location @yourapplication {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
    }
}
```

**uwsgi.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
module = src.main
callable = app

uid = nginx
gid = nginx

socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock
chown-socket = nginx:nginx
chmod-socket = 664

cheaper = 1
processes = %(%k + 1)
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.9

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        libatlas-base-dev gfortran nginx supervisor

RUN pip3 install uwsgi

COPY ./requirements.txt /project/requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r /project/requirements.txt

RUN useradd --no-create-home nginx

RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
RUN rm -r /root/.cache

COPY server-conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
# COPY server-conf/flask-site-nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
COPY server-conf/uwsgi.ini /etc/uwsgi/
COPY server-conf/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/

COPY src /project/src

WORKDIR /project

ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/project/src"

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "5000:80"
    volumes:
     - .:/project
```

Those are my files which should run my application on an HTTPS connection. I have an index.html file which I added manually and the rules I added manually which does work. But when I try to run my webapp on these settings it doesn't work. When I go to my url with the port it says SSL PROTOCOL ERROR. Am I missing out on something?

I've been trying to get this work for the past 2-3 days. The HTTP did work before but I changed my nginx.conf to try and make it work with HTTPS but no success so far. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Maybe try listen `[::]:443 ipv6only=off;`?

Comment: @Anaksunaman This doesn't work man..

Answer (score 0):

Your Docker compose points to your application routing traffic to port 80, while on your nginx config, your TLS config is for port 443

```
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "5000:80"
```

---

```
   listen 443 ssl http2;
   listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
```

---

Change the container port from 80 to 443 to route it to the TLS listener

Comment: Didn't work, when I changed port to 443, I couldn't reach the page at all.